# Find number of non-congruent parallelogram of perimeter $40$ with integer side lengths and at least one diagonal of integer length.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Find number of non-congruent parallelogram of perimeter $40$ with integer side lengths and at least one diagonal of integer length.

My working:

Let sides be $a\le b$ and one diagonal of integer length be $c$

Now we have $b-a<c<a+b$
$\implies 20-2a<c<20$
$\implies$ number of values of $c$ for given $a$ is $2a-1\implies $ total choices are $\sum_{a=1}^{10}(2a-1)=100$

But here there may be some repetition due to both diagonal becomes integer!

Length of other diagonal will be $\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}.$

Now should I check all cases ?

Answer (score 1):

A parallelogram can be thought of as two separate triangles. Therefore, we only need to consider one triangle, with smaller sides $a$ and $b$, with some other side $c$. (WLOG $a \leqslant b$)

We have that $a+b=20$. By triangle inequality theorem, $c<20$. This becomes a much easier casework question.

We see that this easily boils down to $1 + 3 + 5 + . . . 19$. This comes from solving for the number of integral values of $c$ for the cases when $(a= 1, b = 19), (a=2, b=18) . . .$ etc. This is equal to $10^2 = 100$. Thus, there are a $100$ total paralellograms.

Comment: The question specified at least one integer diagonal, not exactly one.

Comment: But there will be some repetition when both diagonal becomes integer

Comment: Dear sde7, I did the same as you are doing got 100 but we can see that if a=10,b=10 then for c= 16 or 12 we get same parallelogram!! In fact now I proved that this the only case in which both diagonal becomes integer so actual answer is 99